# Count Based on 2 date Ranges for 2 different columns

Tags: sql, datetime, count, date-range

Having an issue writing a report.
I am trying to count on the number of enquiries Issued and passed, they both have a datetime field

The problem im having is the results are coming back incorrect.

Running this code gives me  126 for passed

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Passed FROM BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
Inner Join  BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.Id = pm.FK_ProfileId
WHERE p.CaseTypeId IN (1,2,9,15) AND CONVERT(DATE,pm.DatePassed,103) BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

When i run the issued query I get 223

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Issued FROM BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
Inner Join  BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.Id = pm.FK_ProfileId
WHERE p.CaseTypeId IN (1,2,9,15) AND CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateAppIssued,103) BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

These figures are correct so i put it in one query like so.

```
SELECT COUNT(pm.DateAppIssued) AS Issued,COUNT(pm.DatePassed) AS Passed FROM BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
Inner Join  BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.Id = pm.FK_ProfileId
WHERE p.CaseTypeId IN (1,2,9,15) 
AND (CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateAppIssued,103) BETWEEN @Start AND @End
OR CONVERT(DATE,pm.DatePassed,103) BETWEEN @Start AND @End)
```

This gives me Issued 265 and passed 185
I have tried many different variation but still cant get the correct figures
I hope i have explained this well enough, any help would be much appreciated.
Rusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have the both the conditions in the `where` clause with an `or` condition, you are seeing a different result. Use them in the aggregation itself.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(case when CONVERT(DATE,pm.DateAppIssued,103) BETWEEN @Start AND @End then 1 end) AS Issued,
COUNT(case when CONVERT(DATE,pm.DatePassed,103) BETWEEN @Start AND @End then 1 end) AS Passed 
FROM BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
Inner Join  BPS.dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm ON p.Id = pm.FK_ProfileId
WHERE p.CaseTypeId IN (1,2,9,15)
```

Comment: Thanks VKP much appreciated, So basically your saying if there is a date in the issued or passed that matches the date range then count as 1. Thats a perfect solution i thought i could achieve that in the where clause. I am going to save this code for future use as i have allot of reports like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `COUNT(pm.DateAppIssued)` in the last query, all you're counting are the rows that ***have a value for that field***. There's absolutely no logic there about whether the date is in a particular range.

In fact, it's possible if none of the rows overlap (i.e., all the rows with `passed` in the right range are different from the rows with `issued` in the right range) and all the rows have a date, you'd actually get a number as big as 349 there (i.e., 126 + 223).

***Solution***: What's wrong with having two separate queries? You want two different numbers based on two different criteria, so you're selecting them separately. That's not bad design; it's perfectly sensible.

Comment: Hi VoteyDisciple im using report builder to show the results of the query you cant add to different queries to one dataset meaning i cant add both queries to a table